# converting string in clear integer

Tags: c++

I want to write a function for converting string into 3 integers which can be passed into another function.

```
exsistingFunction(int parameter1, int p2, int p3);
```

Suppose that I want pass 128,2,4 as parameters 1,2,3 respectively. I want to pass it like this,

```
exsistingFunction(expectedfn("128,2,4"));
```

could anybody explain what expectedfn() is going to be?

Comment: First [split the line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) on the comma, then [convert each string to integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Sounds like a reasonable solution to me. However, you can't call one single function and expect it to return three values. C++ simply doesn't work that way. However, you could use [a tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) with three value and return that from `expectedfn` and have `existingFunction` accept that tuple (or write a wrapper that expands the tuple).

Comment: @wreckralph It is impossible. You have to change the parameter list of exsistingFunction.

Comment: in go you could do it - I love go:-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vlad, you can not return 3 values from a function.

However, another option is possible.

Create a function existingFunction(std::string s).

This function could use stringstream(s), then extract the 3 int parameters from s.  It would then invoke existingfunction(int, int, int).

This can work because the two versions of existingFunction() have different signatures.

---

Example code:

```
void existingFunction(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
   std::cout << p1 << " "
             << p2 << " "
             << p3 << " " << std::endl;
}

void existingFunction(std::string s)
{
   std::stringstream ss(s);

   int p1 = 0;
   int p2 = 0;
   int p3 = 0;
   char kar = 0;

   // existingFunction(p1, p2, p3);  // diagnostic to confirm 0's

   ss >> p1 >> kar
      >> p2 >> kar
      >> p3;

   existingFunction(p1, p2, p3);
}


int t169(void)
{
   existingFunction("128,2,4");
   return(0);
}
```

---

I prefer the above, but have used the following idea (adding a default parameter) to add the functionality desired without necessitating a re-write of all the invocations:

```
void existingFunction(int p1, int p2, int p3, 
                      std::string s = "")
{
   if(s.size()) { // s dominates p1,p2,p3 when provided
      std::stringstream ss(s);
      char kar = 0;
      ss >> p1 >> kar
         >> p2 >> kar
         >> p3;
   }
   // when s.size() == 0, use p1,p2,p3

   std::cout << p1 << " "
             << p2 << " "
             << p3 << " " << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _you can not return 3 values from a function_ - really? tuple<int, int, int>?

Comment: strictly speaking that's returning one thing, a tuple. Compare this with go which allows a function to return multiple values.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  I like tuples, fine, but that approach would involve changing the signature of the function and  every invocation (possibly very numerous).  The approach I've suggested is a relatively simple addition to the existing code, with no impact to things he need not change.

Comment: You guys are right that technically it returns one value. tuple allows to easily pack multiple values into one.